# BeanIO - Failed to Load Default Stream Factory Implementation Class

Tags: android, bean-io

I'm trying to use BeanIO to read/write to a csv file in an Android application.  When I try to create an instance of the `StreamFactory`, I get the following error:

```
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305): org.beanio.BeanIOException: Failed to load stream factory implementation class 'org.beanio.internal.DefaultStreamFactory'
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.StreamFactory.newInstance(StreamFactory.java:353)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.StreamFactory.newInstance(StreamFactory.java:304)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at com.catfoodcalc.io.CatFoodFileUtil.getBeanReader(CatFoodFileUtil.java:20)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at com.catfoodcalc.io.CatFoodFileUtil.retrieveSavedCatFoodList(CatFoodFileUtil.java:42)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at com.catfoodcalc.MainActivity.saveCatFood(MainActivity.java:176)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at com.catfoodcalc.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:164)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at com.catfoodcalc.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:194)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305): Caused by: org.beanio.BeanIOException: Unable to validate using XSD: JAXP provider [org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@41bc27f8] does not support XML Schema.
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.internal.config.xml.XmlMappingReader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(XmlMappingReader.java:125)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.internal.config.xml.XmlMappingReader.<init>(XmlMappingReader.java:50)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.internal.config.xml.XmlConfigurationLoader.<init>(XmlConfigurationLoader.java:34)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.internal.compiler.StreamCompiler.<init>(StreamCompiler.java:48)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.internal.DefaultStreamFactory.init(DefaultStreamFactory.java:48)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.StreamFactory.newInstance(StreamFactory.java:349)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     ... 15 more
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:86)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.internal.config.xml.XmlMappingReader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(XmlMappingReader.java:119)
03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     ... 20 more
```

The code where this is happening looks like this:

```
    private static BeanReader getBeanReader() {
        StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();  //This is where the above exception is thrown
        factory.load(MAPPING_FILE);
        File inputFile = new File("myFile");
        return factory.createReader("myBeanIOStream", inputFile);
    }
```

I'm new to both Android and BeanIO development, so I apologize if I've missed something obvious here.  I've done a fair amount of googling, and couldn't find anyone with a similar issue.  Is BeanIO even compatible with Android?  Should I be specifying a different `DocumentBuilderFactory` implementation somewhere?

Any help in resolving this error is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's kinda late for answer to this question, but I had to affort to this problem weeks ago. Here is my evaluation and solution:

- At first, if you check your log:

  03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage
  03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:86)
  03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     at org.beanio.internal.config.xml.XmlMappingReader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(XmlMappingReader.java:119)
  03-02 08:52:19.076: E/AndroidRuntime(9305):     ... 20 more

The main problem occurs in DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.

The solution for this is using the library **xerces-for-android** , a library that have an equivalent for DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl, inside beanIO project.

Library in github: https://github.com/MaTriXy/xerces-for-android

- But there you will have another problem inside beanIO. The class BeanUtils needs the class java.beans that is by default in java native. This time I used another library called **droid-java-beans** that have all classes from java.beans:

Library in github: https://github.com/dthommes/droid-java-beans

After adding twose libraries inside your BeanIO project, you have to generate the jar files.

---

If you don't want to do that tired job I've just put these jars inside my drive google account

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P3HPUopjFiAk31qcks_vrDijEPsAkGzQ

PS: I had to put these 3 jars inside my **Android project**

Best regards.